# Numpy Multidimensional Array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, multidimensional-array

I'm new to numpy, I don't understand how the following works:

```
np.array([range(i, i + 3) for i in [2, 4, 6]])
```

and the output is:

```
array([[2, 3, 4],[4, 5, 6],[6, 7, 8]])
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you understand list comprehensions?  `range`?

```
In [12]: [range(i, i + 3) for i in [2, 4, 6]]
Out[12]: [range(2, 5), range(4, 7), range(6, 9)]
```

`np.array` converts the `range` objects to lists, and then builds the array.

```
In [13]: [list(range(i, i + 3)) for i in [2, 4, 6]]
Out[13]: [[2, 3, 4], [4, 5, 6], [6, 7, 8]]
In [14]: np.array([list(range(i, i + 3)) for i in [2, 4, 6]])
Out[14]: 
array([[2, 3, 4],
       [4, 5, 6],
       [6, 7, 8]])
```

So basically it's just a variation on the textbook example of making an array from a list of lists:

```
In [15]: np.array([[1,2,3],[10,11,12]])
Out[15]: 
array([[ 1,  2,  3],
       [10, 11, 12]])
```

Comment: I understand the In & Out [12]. What I don't understand is if range is (i, i+3) for i in [2, 4, 6], how is the array outputting [2, 3, 4], [4, 5, 6], [6, 7, 8]?

Comment: It's `range(i, i+3)`.  So if `i` is `2`, we get `range(2,5)`, which expanded to a list is `[2,3,4]`.